# Log4j socketappender configuration for grails app?

Tags: grails, log4j, logstash

I have a Grails 2.3.7 app.

In Config.groovy I have added -

```
log4j = {
appenders {
        rollingFile name:'stdout', file:"${logDirectory}/myapp.log".toString()
        rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:"${logDirectory}/stacktrace_myapp.log".toString()
        appender new org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender(name:'central',
             layout:pattern(conversionPattern:'%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n'),
             remoteHost: 'localhost', port: 4560, reconnectionDelay: 10000,locationInfo:true)
}
info   'grails.app'    
error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate',
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
 //debug 'org.apache.http.wire'
}
```

I have also installed Logstash to listen to the log messages. logstash conf. file -

```
input {
log4j {
mode => "server"
host => "localhost"
port => 4560
type => log4j
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But I do not see any logs being parsed by logstash. That is, there is no output on either stdout or the elasticsearch interface.

> localhost:9200/_search?pretty

Though I am able to see logs being generated in myapp.log file

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line

```
root { info "central", "stdout", "stacktrace" }
```

after the appenders block did the trick

Comment: How to tell the SocketAppender to consolidate the logs to DailyAppender?